# How to display Parent record with total number of its Child record in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parent-child, counter-cache

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: :creator_id
  belongs_to :deal_task, foreign_key: :relation_id
end
class DealTask < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :attachments, foreign_key: :relation_id
end
```

I have parent table called DealTask and child table called Attachment

I want a list of DealTask records with associated total number of attachments

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. As a first step, please add the code you already tried and describe how it doesnt work for you.

Comment: **DealTask.all.map{|deal_task| Attachment.where(relation_id: deal_task.id).count}**    i tried this but it gives me only count, not full _parent_ record

Comment: What exactly do you want as your return value? A `hash`? An `object` of some kind? (If an `object`, of what `class`?) (Please add answers to your original question rather than adding to comments.)

Comment: Like what? You didn't add anything to your original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the best solution for Parent child relationship count

```
counter_cache: true
```

because all above queries take too much time to load from database

so you all must prefer to use this

1-> Add one column in     **Parent table** called **DealTask**

```
rails g migration AddAttachmentsCountToDealTask attachments_count:integer
```

2-> Open Migration add Edit it

```
class AddAttachmentCountToDealTask < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]

 def up
  add_column :deal_tasks, :attachments_count, :integer, default: 0
  DealTask.reset_column_information
  DealTask.find_each do |deal_task|
    DealTask.reset_counters deal_task.id, :attachments
  end
 end
 def down
  remove_column :deal_tasks, attachments_count
 end
end
```

So when you rollback the migration it will not raise an error or exception

you can also use any loop instead of using

```
find_each, DealTask.all.each do...end
```

but yes, While **resetting counter** Must use class name  like

```
DealTask.reset_counters
```

3-> Set Counter cache

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :deal_task, foreign_key: :relation_id, counter_cache: true
end
class DealTask < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :attachments, foreign_key: :relation_id
end
```

suppose name of your model is **sub_tasks** than your counter_cache column must be

```
sub_tasks_count
```

if you want your own column name than you have to specify that column name in counter_cache

suppose column name is total_subtasks than

```
belongs_to :deal_task, foreign_key: :relation_id, counter_cache: :total_subtasks
```

and make changes accordingly for updating counter_cache

now when you **Add** any **Attachment**, **attachments_count** column increase by 1 and this is done automatically by **counter_cache

one Problem is there 
** when you delete any child counter_cache is unable to decrease **

so for that solution make a callback

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :deal_task, foreign_key: :relation_id, counter_cache: true
 before_destroy :reset_counter
 private
 def reset_counter
  DealTask.reset_counters(self.relation.id, :attachments)
 end
end
```

so when you delete any attachments it will reset countet_cache for its Parent by **relation_id** which is parent_id or Foreign_key for attachments

for more info 
see video on  [Railscast counter cache 23](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column)

Answer (score 2):

```
DealTask.all.map do |deal_task|
  deal_task.
    attributes.
    with_indifferent_access.
    slice(:id, :name).
    merge!(total_attachment: deal_task.attachments.count)
end
```

Or, if you don't care about indifferent access and you don't mind having all the `DealTask` attributes, you can write this with on a single line:

```
DealTask.all.map{|deal_task| deal_task.attributes.merge!(total_attachments: deal_task.attachments.count)}
```

Breaking it down...

```
DealTask.all.map do |deal_task|
  ...
end
```

Is going to return an `array`. The `array` will contain the results of the `do` block.

```
deal_task.
  attributes.
  with_indifferent_access
```

Gives you the attributes of each `deal_task` in a hash that can be access with `strings` or `symbols` (thus, "indifferent_access").

```
deal_task.
  attributes.
  with_indifferent_access.
  slice(:id, :name)
```

Keeps only the `:id` and `:name` of the `deal_task` hash.

```
merge!(total_attachments: deal_task.attachments.count)
```

Adds the attachments count to your hash with the key `total_attachments`.

Results should look something like:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'name1', total_attachments: 12},
  {id: 2, name: 'name2', total_attachments: 3}
]
```

Comment: that is the Answer which i exactly want

Comment: Thank you @jvillian

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DealTask.all.map { |deal_task| deal_task.attachments.ids }.count
```

Comment: still not getting output which i want

Comment: do want separate DealTask row with its child attachment count values?

Answer (score 0):

`DealTask.first.attachments.count #This will give count of attachemenets`

```
#To show all records and all the count

DealTask.find_each do |dt|
      print dt.inspect
      print "\n"
      print dt.attachments.count
end
```

Or

```
DealTask.joins(:attachments).select("deal_tasks.*, count(attachements.id) as count").group("deal_tasks.id")
```

For much nicer format

```
DealTask.joins(:attachments)
        .select("deal_tasks.id, deal_tasks.name, count(attachements.id) as attachments")
        .group("deal_tasks.id")
        .collect(&:attributes)
#This will gve you something like

[
{"id"=>34332630, "name"=>"some name", "attachments"=>1}, 
{"id"=>71649461, "name"=>"some name", "attachments"=>1}
]
```

This will be lot faster as you get all data in a single query

Comment: i want to send DealTask Record with total attachment as **JOSN** so this will not work

Comment: @KetanMangukiya You can take it any format, see the updated answer. This will be lot faster as you get all data in a single query